# Creating a socket leads to Network is unreachable - ENETUNREACH

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with creating a socket. The error is as follows

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.103 (port 23): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

Here is part of my code

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + wifiName + "\"";
wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);

if (networkId != -1) 
{
   wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
   new Thread(new GetMacThread()).start();
}

class GetMacThread implements Runnable{
private Socket socket;
private int portNumber = 23;
private String myIP = "192.168.1.103";
@Override
public void run() 
{

    try {

        socket = new Socket(myIP, portNumber);
        System.out.println("Socket Thread:"+socket);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that it is not network problem (IP and port are good, I have also added permissions in manifest) because I tested it with connected WIFI network and commented line `wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)` and socket was made properly. Program was working then.  So the problem is that, it is working only with previously turned on WiFi.

I also tried first to check wifi connection with ConnectivityManager before creating socket but it changed nothing.

Have you got any ideas why socket fails in this particular order?

Comment: I probably found a solution. Android couldnt create socket because it takes more time to make Wifi connection and ConnectivityManager checks only if the Wifi is turned on(checking for whether Wi-Fi is enabled, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's connected). So I used Broadcast Receiver to check if the connection had been made.

Comment: Your solution gave me a great clue of what was going wrong in my own project, so I solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method [ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) helped me in a similar case. You can find additional information here - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html.